# Calculating isobars

Tags: algorithm

If I have a set of readings (eg pressures) taken at lat-long points what are the algorithm(s) can I use to determine isobars?  The recorded positions are not on any fixed pattern, and we can assume I have a few hundred over a reasonable area.

Comment: Lots of this kind of thing on [gis.se] - try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contour

Comment: Create a triangulation on those points (using, e.g., a Delaunay triangulation), and then run your isobars through the edges whose endpoints are on opposite sides of that iso value.